# How to get the number of members in a class at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11

I often encounter situations where I have to implement custom copy/move constructors. However some time later, it occurs that the class gets extended with a new member and this custom copy/move constructor is not updated, so I'm searching for a way to prevent the code from compiling without updating these methods.

Header code:

```
class MyClass
   {
   public:
       MyClass(const MyClass &rhs);
       // ...
   private:
       std::string                 _s;
       std::unique_ptr<OtherClass> _owned;
       bool                        _b;
   };
```

Cpp code:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &rhs)
    : _s(rhs._s)
    , _b(rhs._b)
    {
    if (rhs._owned)
       _owned = rhs._owned->clone();
    }
```

So, if I add some member to MyClass, example: `std::size_t _size;` than I would like a compilation error for the copy constructor.

My current solution is to add:

```
static_assert(sizeof(MyClass) == 32, "...");
```

near this implementation of the copy constructor. All of this works fine, unfortunately this only works when the size of the class increases. So if I instead add `bool _b2;` all compiles unfortunately.

So instead of checking the size, I would like to check the number of members. Unfortunately I haven't found this yet. Are there any suggestions?

I've already considered:

- banning `bool` in favor of `short`, though it breaks all sense of intention.
- replacing `bool` by bitset, however different values can't have different names
- Put all default copyable members in separate struct, which introduces complexity
- Add `static const auto` with number of members to the class, hoping this gets updated on adding a member

All these ideas however need code/guideline changes, so ideally I would just like to write `static_assert(number_of_members<MyClass>::value == 3, "...");`, any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the number of members of class using the language itself. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than I can prove otherwise.

Comment: C++ doesn't have static reflection, no.

Comment: A good Lint tool should give you warnings when members are missing from constructors, copy assignments, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Rule of Zero**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three):

> Classes that have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators should deal exclusively with ownership (which follows from the Single Responsibility Principle). Other classes should not have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators.

In this case, if you simply had a:

```
template <class T>
struct clone_unique_ptr {
    std::unique_ptr<T> p;

    clone_unique_ptr(const clone_unique_ptr& rhs)
    : p(rhs.p ? rhs.p->clone() : nullptr)
    { }

    // rest of special members
};
```

Then you wouldn't have to write anything special:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(const MyClass&) = default;
private:
   std::string                  _s;
   clone_unique_ptr<OtherClass> _owned;
   bool                         _b;
};
```

Comment: Would work, if all code would have the same API, unfortunately refactoring takes time :S  and if you like to use move-constructors in MSVC2013, you can't use =default. However I like the idea! TNX a lot!

Comment: It ain't what I was look for, though I believe it is the best solution to the problem. So I'll be accepting this.

Answer (score -1):

C++ does not have [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386404/find-the-list-of-member-variables-of-a-class-and-their-types) built in.  However, you can try using an external library [xCppRefl](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/reflcpp/) which should provide reflection (Never used it before and it's quite old so let me know if using the library works for you).

Stepping through the source if you do

```
std::vector<DataMember> dataMembers = className.getDataMembers();
```

And then run `assert(dataMembers.size() == expectedNumMembers)` you should be able to test if the number of members in a class is what you expect.

Comment: He wants a compile time solution