# C++ - Checking all member variables for condition

Tags: c++, class, member

Simplified example of my situation:

I have a class with 3 member variables, all integers, e.g.

```
class Foo
{
   public:
      int A;
      int B;
      int C;
};
```

I want to have a function that returns a Boolean `true` if all of the member variables are 0 and `false` otherwise.

Easy enough, could be accomplished with this member function:

```
bool all_zero()
{
   return (A == 0 && B == 0 && C == 0);
}
```

I can do this if necessary.

However, this is not ideal in my situation because:

1. I am not the only person who manages this software.
2. Occasionally, new member variables are added to this class (e.g. `int D`).
3. This is a very large C++ project, and we often don't add new member variables to the class directly by manually modifying the code - instead, we have custom tools that automatically modify the code for us. Therefore, it is pretty rare that we make manual modification to this class.
4. Additionally, since this project is so large, the `all_zero` function above could easily be overlooked (i.e. someone could forget, or be completely unaware to add `&& D == 0` to the function if a new member variable is added).

All that said... here is my question:

Is there any way to modify this `all_zero` function such that it always checks *all* member variables (of `int` type), without needing to tell the function to explicitly check each one? By the way, I am also OK if this functionality is accomplished outside of the class (rather than inside the class with a member function).

I am hoping that I don't have to resort to this, but worst case scenario for me here is that I can stick with this original `all_zero` idea above and just proceduralize the adding of a new member variable to this class, basically telling anyone who adds a member variable to the class must also manually modify this `all_zero` function.

Comment: If you use an automatic tool to generate the class, why can't it generate the function as well? Seems like a self imposed hardship

Comment: Are all the member variables `int` types?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that it would be possible if the members were in the form of an array.

Comment: @StoryTeller I cannot modify the tool because it was provided to us by a vendor, and they did not provide us with the source code.

Comment: Guessing where @Bathsheba is going, can't you make an array instead of having distinct variables? Because then you could easily use e.g. [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) or other [standard algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: You can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386404/find-the-list-of-member-variables-of-a-class-and-their-types which explains it's not possible

Comment: So? Check to see if the tool can be configured, or ask the vendor for an enhancement. It's not unheard of.

Comment: @Bathsheba No. The classes are very large, and contain many types.

Comment: [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) might help as viewing your struct as `tuple`. Then it is normal meta prog.

Comment: "This is a very large C++ project, and we often don't add new member variables to the class directly by manually modifying the code - instead, we have custom tools that automatically modify the code for us. Therefore, it is pretty rare that we make manual modification to this class." Can you modify the custom tool to generate the function automatically as well?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi No, I don't have the source code to modify the tool. The contractor who provided us with the tool, the contract has expired so we'd have to pay them to modify it, which is not worth doing solely to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bool all_zero() const
{
   Foo f{}, g{};
   g = *this;  
   return ::memcmp(&f, &g, sizeof(f));
}
```

is one way, assuming your class is *trivially copyable*. The `{}` will zero-initialise the members *including any padding bits*, and the compiler generated assignment operator will copy the members for comparison.

Quite possibly we will soon get a compiler-generated `==` which would probably be better. See https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-the-default-comparison-proposal-bjarne-stroustrup.

Finally, if the comparison method needs to be outside the class, then consider

```
bool all_zero(const Foo& f)
{
    Foo g{}, h{};
    h = f;
    return ::memcmp(&g, &h, sizeof(f));
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to think if padding at the end is likely or not. If there's padding, its content is unspecified. It may end up giving false negatives.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You're the expert here. I'm wondering if the padding has to be initialised with a default constructor in the same way as it is with `{}`.

Comment: I'm checking, at the moment. I don't remember if zero-initialization applies to padding too

Comment: @StoryTeller: I have a *feeling* (and my feelings normally mean I'm wrong) that it the behaviour is better defined in C than C++.

Comment: I hate to be *that guy*, but it's backwards. [C++ accounts for padding](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#6.2). While [C... not so much](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note310).

Comment: But again, this hinges on `this` being value->zero initialized. It's a neat way to leverage C++, but I'd add a cautionary note.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Dunnit.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks, not sure if this will work or not. I will test and let you know.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889: If std::is_trivially_copyable is true for your type, and you do all the initialisations as I advise, it will work.

Comment: @Bathsheba Also, is it possible to have this functionality *outside* of the class? This would actually be ideal in this situation, because then I wouldn't have to interfere at all with the tool that automatically generates this class.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889: So long as you ensure that all objects are zero-intiialised then that would be fine. The issue is that you need to initialise the padding bits for true portability.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks, can you please edit you post to show what the code would look like outside of the class?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889: Dunnit. Also got round the padding issue.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Got round the padding issue. I believe my solution is now truly portable, if a little *wild*, if you get my meaning. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Bathsheba Any reason you avoided `static const Foo g{};
    return f == g;` as your impl?

Comment: @UKMonkey: Are you from the future? We don't have a compiler generated `==` yet.

Comment: @Bathsheba sorry - good point; I'd missed that the auto-generated code didn't include an `==` for some reason.  But thanks - I'll work with C++21 anyway if you don't mind :)

Comment: I don't think this really solve the OP problem, two of his requirements: "Is there any way to modify this all_zero function such that it always checks all member variables (of int type)?" At the questions are all int types he replied: " No. The classes are very large, and contain many types." So, there is no guarantee for memcmp to work reliably even if the class is trivially copyable. For example: struct A { int a; char b; } b can be any value and it should not have any effect in the result of all_zero() function

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi huh? Why wouldn't the value of `b` affect `memcmp`? It most certainly does.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding the OP, it wants to compare only the int data members. So, for example A f; f.a = 0; f.b = 'B'; and A g; g.a = 0; g.b='C' they should both return true to all_zero(). I don't see how memcmp can fit the bill

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi that's not what I got from the question. "I want to have a function that returns a Boolean true if **all of the member variables** are 0 and false otherwise."  The `int` variables are just an example.

Comment: @bolov your interpretation might be the correct one, I guess all_zero is not are really good name for that kind of function then

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi The question clarifies at the bottom that I want to check only all members *of int type*. I assumed this wasn't an issue because Bathsheba specifically asked if there were other types other than `int` before posting this answer.

Comment: I find that relying on value-initialization to initialize the padding bits is quite obscure. Combining `memcmp` with `memset`, on the other hand, is something almost any C/C++ programmer should understand. You might also want to add the obligatory warning regarding floating-point shenanigans, i.e. [negative zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_zero). Note that `-0.0 == 0.0`, i.e. this is not an orthogonal issue.

Comment: @bolov it seems that the OP wants to disregard any data member that is not an int in the function. So, memcmp cannot be used here